# Why does the voting daily limit apply to comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, voting, rate-limiting, comment-votes

I don't understand why the voting limit applies to comments. After hitting the upvote limit, I can still vote comments for some time, but after a few votes I cannot vote comments anymore. Why is this? As comment upvotes do not give reputation and there is no downvoting comments I don't understand what is the purpose of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments *aren't* tied to the post vote limit, they simply have their own limit.

Comment: I was asking what's the purpose of the limit, however this was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @theo2003 then maybe clarify. Your title and post are two different questions.

Comment: Is there a limit on comments per post, meaning that comments are not visible? All my comments are visible I think.